# JavaScript - declaring global variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I declare variable:

```
var Cash_player=0
```

It is used in function:

```
function send_stats(message) {
  document.querySelector("#stats").innerText = message;
}

send_stats(`Stats:
Gold:${Cash_player}
`)
```

And then it is increased in other function:

```
function win() {
Cash_player += 15;
send_stats()
}
```

However the result is `Undefined`. Could you please help me to increase the value and then to show it using `send_stats()`?

Comment: If you want to pass a parameter, you need to pass the parameter.

Comment: You're calling send_stats with no argument: `send_stats()`. Thus `message` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to update the `innerText` to `Cash_player` without passing it again and again to `function`. You update the text to `Stats:Gold:${Cash_player}` inside `send_stats`

```js
let Cash_player = 0;
function send_stats(message) {
  document.querySelector("#stats").innerText = `Stats:Gold:${Cash_player}`;
}

function win() {
  Cash_player += 15;
  send_stats()
}

send_stats()
```

```html
<div id="stats"></div>
<button onclick="win()">Win</button>
```